# no Auto activation triggers for Java on OS X eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, autocomplete

normally, there is Auto activation 
here's how it looks like:     https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ3lB.png

But now I'm using OS X, 
I can't find the Auto Activation in Preferences >> JAVA >> Editor >> Content Assistant
I just want to set all characters as triggers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'there is no such function'? That preference page is just the same on Mac OS X Eclipse.

Comment: I didn't find the Auto Activation in Preferences >> JAVA >> Editor >> Content Assistant

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this?

Comment: I have tried Eclipse Standard OS X 64bit(from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and Eclipse Standard 4.3.2 in Eclipse Kepler SR2 Packages.(from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2), none of them has such configuration block

Comment: Strange, on my Mac both Eclipse 4.3.2 and 4.4 have this section as expected. Looking at the source of the page there is nothing that would leave it out.

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.9.4, do you thing this is the reason? I have used auto triggers for a long time, without this, I feel very very uncomfortable.